# LazyVerticalGrid con detectTransformGestures: quiero cambiar las posiciones de las imágenes que se encuentran el lazyVerticalGrid "index" a "index +1"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Estoy en un proyecto utilizando LazyVerticalGrid  y este mi código:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns =  GridCells.Fixed(columns)) {
            itemsIndexed(parts) { index,_->      
                Image(
                    bitmap = parts[index].asImageBitmap(),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                    modifier = modifier
                         .pointerInput(index){
                            detectTransformGestures { _, pan,_, _ ->
                                if(Math.abs(pan.x) > Math.abs(pan.y)
                                ){
                                    if(pan.x>0
                                    ){

                                        val index2= index+1
                                        val temporalImagen = parts[index]
                                        parts[index] = parts[index2]
                                        parts[index2] = temporalImagen
                                     }
                                 }             
                             }
                       }
                }
```

En este código quisiera cambiar la imagen que se encuentra en el index por la imagen que se encuentra en index2 cuando arrastro la imagen del index a la derecha, quisiera que me ayuden.

Comment: creo que el problema esta en  ``` val index2= index+1
                                        val temporalImagen = parts[index]
                                        parts[index] = parts[index2]
                                        parts[index2] = temporalImagen```

Comment: ` val index2= index+1 val temporalImagen = parts[index] parts[index] = parts[index2] parts[index2] = temporalImagen`